# Sharing Snowsight Dashboard to user by commands

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Apart from using web ui is there any way(command/script) to share snowsight dashboards to other users.

Answer (score 0):

There are two [Snowflake Ideas](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) you could vote for:

- "Connect github with snoflake or snowsight dashboard"
- "Public API for manipulating Snowsight dashboards"

---

[sfsnowsightextensions](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfsnowsightextensions):

> Snowflake Snowsight Extensions wrap Snowsight features that do not have API or SQL alternatives, **such as manipulating Dashboards and Worksheets,** and retrieving Query Profile and step timings.
>
> **This project is not an officialy supported product of Snowflake. Use at your own risk.**